# grunt uglify task failing

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

When running grunt, I get the following error:

> Warning: Unable to write "client/dist/js/build.js" file (Error code: undefined). Use --force to continue.

The config of uglify in my `Gruntfile.js` :

```
uglify: {
      build: {
        src: ['client/src/js/*.js'],
        dest:['client/dist/js/build.js']
      }
    }
```

I'm using `grunt-contrib-uglify`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming your Grunt Version is 0.4.0, AFAIK you are not using the most recent Syntax (See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#usage-examples).

Try

```
uglify: {
    build: {
        files: {
            'client/dist/js/build.js': ['client/src/js/*.js']
        }
    }
}
```

I am also not sure if the wildcards are handled properly.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is marked as solved, but I still prefer [this answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523431/1092815) because you can easily use the files again for an other command without writing them twice.

In short, answer says

```
//Does not work
src: ['client/src/js/*.js'],
dest: ['client/dist/js/build.js']
//Works
src: ['client/src/js/*.js'],
dest: 'client/dist/js/build.js'
```

**Tested working example** without writing files twice:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      build: {
        src: ['client/src/js/*.js'],
        dest: 'client/dist/js/build.js'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: '<%= uglify.build.src %>',
        tasks: ['uglify']
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'uglify',
    ]);
  grunt.registerTask('dev', [
    'watch'
    ]);
};
```

Notice that `'<%= uglify.build.src %>'` is very handy ;)

**Execution**

```
$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...OK
>> File "client/src/js/hello.js" changed.
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
File "client/dist/js/build.js" created.
Uncompressed size: 15 bytes.
Compressed size: 32 bytes gzipped (15 bytes minified).

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: +1 this is a great solution. In addition to this, I have my package.json generated with my img, js, and css paths so that I can reference them with `<%= pkg.path.js %>` etc.