# Grunt Concat cannot write to file

Tags: gruntjs

Just installed latest Grunt on Ubuntu 12.04. Here is my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
//project configuration
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        slides :  {
            src : ['src/top.html', 'src/bottom.html'],
            dest : ['build/index.html']
        }
    }
});

//enable plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:slides']);
}
```

This creates the build/ directory fine, but gives me the output of:

> Running "concat:slides" (concat) task Warning: Unable to write
>   "build/index.html" file (Error code: undefined). Use --force to
>   continue.

I tried running chmod 777 on the directory, as I thought it might have something to do with permissions, but that didn't seem to change anything.

How can I make it so Grunt will write to build/index.html?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
//Does not work
dest : ['build/index.html']
```

Works as a string, but not an array:

```
//Works
dest : 'build/index.html'
```

Comment: I had the same issue, found a similar question and gave [a detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17626981/1092815) based on your answer. All credits goes to you, thanks alot :)

Comment: This answer helped me fix another syntax error. Make sure to use 'dest' and not 'dst'.

Comment: Mine was "desc" instead "dest". (:

Answer (score 0):

I changed tasks/concat.js to accept arrays for dest:

```
// Write the destination file.
// If f.dest is an array take the first element
var dest  = ([].concat(f.dest))[0]
grunt.file.write(dest, src);
```

but later I decided to use the files form instead of src/dest:

```
files: { 'dest.js': ['a.js', 'b.js'] }
```